# Is there a way to be notified if there is an irregular pronunciation?

Tags: prononciation, oral, ressources

For example crier in the future simple form is crierai and it is conjugated just like parler-parlerai BUT! as it was pointed out in this video to me https://youtu.be/IEbpqZSBUFY?t=285. the pronunciation is /kʁiʁe/ and not /kʁi**ə**ʁe/ as one would have expected.
Is there a search engine a website or anything that points out things like this in an exhaustive way instead of going through every single conjugation in every single tense and mood and listen to them one by one?
Or is there a rule that covers all pronunciation exceptions?
I was thinking of something like wordreference.com and its practice to show which part of the word is irregular with a different color but for pronunciation.

Comment: There's no exception in this case, vowel+<e> is always pronounced as the vowel (or the vowel but longer in some dialects), whether it's at the end of a word or in the middle. "crierai" is pronounced exactly like crie+rai, "suera" like sue+ra, scierie like scie+rie and so on.

Comment: I always love when the answer's scope doesn't match the question's although I still have to thank you for your comment and your time. ...Even if in this particular case crierai is not an exception -following your lead and not the french teachers in the video- can you still show me how you would go about finding out whether a new word and all of its forms/conjugations/whatever have an unusual pronunciation. I imagine there are still exceptions lurking around and it would be nice not having to rewrite the question should I remember to do so when one pops up.

Comment: Well I used the term "popping up" loosely because in reality I have to spot it and that's the problem. That's what the resource engine would help me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple sites for french conjugations ([Bescherelle](http://conjugueur.bescherelle.com/ConjugueurWeb/index.jsf?term=crier&options=MTI5LDIzLDg=&verb=Y3JpZXI=), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison) etc.), but they rarely include the pronunciation.

I found [reverso](http://ttps://conjugueur.reverso.net/conjugaison-francais-verbe-crierai.html) which inculdes the pronunciation as a sound (click on the speaker icon).

[image]

There's also the **CNRTL** site's [*Morphologie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/crierai) tab where one can enter any verb or conjugated form obtain the phonetic (in a strange but understandable phonetic alphabet) :
[image]

I think the second one is better for you as you can see the phonetic for multiple forms at once without clicking each one (the sound does not seem to work in Firefox, though).